# Weird error while using Regex.Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find how many times a () pattern appears in a string; here is the code:

```
int pMatches = (Regex.Matches("(", newDrug).Count + Regex.Matches(")", newDrug).Count)/2;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Quantifier {x,y} following nothing
```

Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the **entire** error message. This is only a fraction.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

The first is that you have the arguments to [`Regex.Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx) in the reverse order.  This is causing the input string to be treated as the pattern, and `"("` to be treated as the text to match it against.  (It appears that your input may start with a `{` character, which makes it an invalid regular expression, hence the error message.)

```
Regex.Matches(newDrug, "(");
```

The second is that `(` is a special regular expression character and needs to be escaped:

```
Regex.Matches(newDrug, Regex.Escape("("))
```